# How to prevent Lotus Notes from saving a document created by a DXL Import?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I followed this link enabling me to setup a hotspot in a richtext field - works like charm.
http://ozinisle.blogspot.de/2010/11/lotusscript-code-to-append-hotspot-to.html

Only problem is, as the user(s) usually do(es) not have deletion rights, the document created by the import stays stored in the database. In LotusScript e.g. I can create a new temporary document and work with it, and if I'm not saving it, it just disappears at the end of the function.

Is there a similar way or parameter for DXL import which allows me to just drop the document after I got my rtitem?

Alternatively, can someone point out to me if it is possible to create **only** the temporary richtext item in/on a document I created as tempdoc via LotusScript?
My search on the web did not get any results and my tries to reduce the linked function always resulted in the error 4518 (which is described in the help document of "DXLImporter"); if I read the help right, the DXLImporter only supports the db as valid output (thus expecting documents being created via DXL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to import DXL without creating a document.

The easiest solution is to create the temporary document in users "cache.ndk". The user has definitely the right to delete documents there. So, you'd replace the line "Set db = session.CurrentDatabase" in code you linked to with

```
Set db = session.Getdatabase("", "cache.ndk", false)
```

The rest of the code would stay the same.

*As an alternative*, use the more classic approach running an agent on server to delete the temporary document. Create an agent which deletes the document, set property "Run on behalf of" to someone who is allowed to delete documents in database and call the agent from your script with

```
agent.RunOnServer(noteID)
```

Comment: I do not believe you'll find a cleaner approach. Personally, I would probably create my own temporary database rather than using cache.ndk, but that's because cache.ndk is pretty much of a mystery to me and I don't like messing around with things I don't control. Knut is braver than I am :-)

Comment: Thanks @Richard :-), but, as long as you delete documents shortly after usage you won't have issues with cache.ndk. That is at least my experience...

Comment: Using the cache.ndk is a great approach, @KnutHerrmann . Will try that!

Comment: I've done something similar, using the clipboard database "~clipbrd.ncf".  The only precaution is to make sure the database exists, and create it if it doesn't.